# Calculating translation value and rotation angle of a rotated 2D image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I have two images which one of them is the Original image and the second one is Transformed image.

I have to find out how many degrees Transformed image was rotated using 3x3 transformation matrix. Plus, I need to find how far translated from origin.

Both images are grayscaled and held in matrix variables. Their sizes are same `[350 500]`.

I have found a few lecture notes like [this](http://www.tamaraberg.com/teaching/Spring_11/CSE364/slides/lecture12.pdf).

Lecture notes say that I should use the following matrix formula for rotation:
[image: Rotation Formula]

For translation matrix the formula is given:

[image: Translation Formula]

Everything is good. But there are two problems:

1. I could not imagine how to implement the formulas using MATLAB.
2. The formulas are shaped to find `x'`,`y'` values but I already have got `x`,`x'`,`y`,`y'` values. I need to find rotation angle (theta) and `t`<sub>`x`</sub> and `t`<sub>`y`</sub>.
3. I want to know the equivailence of `x`, `x'`, `y`, `y'` in the the matrix.

I have got the following code:

```
rotationMatrix = [   cos(theta) sin(theta) 0 ; ...
                    -sin(theta) cos(theta) 0 ; ...
                             0          0  1];


translationMatrix = [  1  0  tx; ...
                       0  1  ty; ...
                       0  0   1];
```

But as you can see, tx, ty, theta variables are not defined before used. How can I calculate `theta`, `t`<sub>`x`</sub> and `t`<sub>`y`</sub>?

PS: It is forbidden to use Image Processing Toolbox functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is essentially a [homography recovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_%28computer_vision%29) problem.  What you are doing is given co-ordinates in one image and the corresponding co-ordinates in the other image, you are trying to recover the combined translation and rotation matrix that was used to warp the points from the one image to the other.

You can essentially combine the rotation and translation into a single matrix by multiplying the two matrices together.  Multiplying is simply compositing the two operations together.  You would this get:

```
H = [cos(theta) -sin(theta)  tx]
    [sin(theta) cos(theta)   ty]
    [    0           0        1]
```

The idea behind this is to find the parameters by minimizing the error through least squares between each pair of points.

Basically, what you want to find is the following relationship:

```
xi_after = H*xi_before
```

`H` is the combined rotation and translation matrix required to map the co-ordinates from the one image to the other.  `H` is also a 3 x 3 matrix, and knowing that the lower right entry (row 3, column 3) is 1, it makes things easier.  Also, assuming that your points are in the augmented co-ordinate system, we essentially want to find this relationship for each pair of co-ordinates from the first image `(x_i, y_i)` to the other `(x_i', y_i')`:

```
[p_i*x_i']   [h11 h12 h13]   [x_i]
[p_i*y_i'] = [h21 h22 h23] * [y_i]
[  p_i   ]   [h31 h32  1 ]   [ 1 ]
```

The scale of `p_i` is to account for homography scaling and vanishing points.  Let's perform a matrix-vector multiplication of this equation.  We can ignore the 3rd element as it isn't useful to us (for now):

```
p_i*x_i' = h11*x_i + h12*y_i + h13
p_i*y_i' = h21*x_i + h22*y_i + h23
```

Now let's take a look at the 3rd element.  We know that `p_i = h31*x_i + h32*y_i + 1`.  As such, substituting `p_i` into each of the equations, and rearranging to solve for `x_i'` and `y_i'`, we thus get:

```
x_i' = h11*x_i + h12*y_i + h13 - h31*x_i*x_i' - h32*y_i*x_i'
y_i' = h21*x_i + h22*y_i + h23 - h31*x_i*y_i' - h32*y_i*y_i'
```

What you have here now are **two** equations for each unique pair of points.  What we can do now is build an over-determined system of equations.  Take each pair and build two equations out of them.  You will then put it into matrix form, i.e.:

> Ah = b

`A` would be a matrix of coefficients that were built from each set of equations using the co-ordinates from the first image, `b` would be each pair of points for the second image and `h` would be the parameters you are solving for.  Ultimately, you are finally solving this linear system of equations reformulated in matrix form:

[image]

You would solve for the vector `h` which can be performed through least squares.  In MATLAB, you can do this via:

```
h = A \ b;
```

A sidenote for you: If the movement between images is truly just a rotation and translation, then h31 and h32 will both be zero after we solve for the parameters.  However, I always like to be thorough and so I will solve for h31 and h32 anyway.

**NB:** This method will only work if you have **at least** 4 *unique* pairs of points.  Because there are 8 parameters to solve for, and there are 2 equations per point, `A` must have at least a rank of 8 in order for the system to be consistent (if you want to throw in some linear algebra terminology in the loop).  You will not be able to solve this problem if you have less than 4 points.

If you want some MATLAB code, let's assume that your points are stored in `sourcePoints` and `targetPoints`.  `sourcePoints` are from the first image and `targetPoints` are for the second image.  Obviously, there should be the same number of points between both images.  It is assumed that both `sourcePoints` and `targetPoints` are stored as `M x 2` matrices.  The first columns contain your `x` co-ordinates while the second columns contain your `y` co-ordinates.

```
numPoints = size(sourcePoints, 1);

%// Cast data to double to be sure
sourcePoints = double(sourcePoints);
targetPoints = double(targetPoints);

%//Extract relevant data
xSource = sourcePoints(:,1);
ySource = sourcePoints(:,2);
xTarget = targetPoints(:,1);
yTarget = targetPoints(:,2);

%//Create helper vectors
vec0 = zeros(numPoints, 1);
vec1 = ones(numPoints, 1);

xSourcexTarget = -xSource.*xTarget;
ySourcexTarget = -ySource.*xTarget;
xSourceyTarget = -xSource.*yTarget;
ySourceyTarget = -ySource.*yTarget;

%//Build matrix
A = [xSource ySource vec1 vec0 vec0 vec0 xSourcexTarget ySourcexTarget; ...
    vec0 vec0 vec0 xSource ySource vec1 xSourceyTarget ySourceyTarget];

%//Build RHS vector
b = [xTarget; yTarget];

%//Solve homography by least squares
h = A \ b;

%// Reshape to a 3 x 3 matrix (optional)
%// Must transpose as reshape is performed
%// in column major format
h(9) = 1; %// Add in that h33 is 1 before we reshape
hmatrix = reshape(h, 3, 3)';
```

Once you are finished, you have a combined rotation and translation matrix.  If you want the `x` and `y` translations, simply pick off column 3, rows 1 and 2 in `hmatrix`.  However, we can also work with the vector of `h` itself, and so h13 would be element 3, and h23 would be element number 6.  If you want the angle of rotation, simply take the appropriate inverse trigonometric function to rows 1, 2 and columns 1, 2.  For the `h` vector, this would be elements 1, 2, 4 and 5.  There will be a bit of inconsistency depending on which elements you choose as this was solved by least squares.  One way to get a good overall angle would perhaps be to find the angles of all 4 elements then do some sort of average.  Either way, this is a good starting point.

### References

I learned about homography a while ago through Leow Wee Kheng's Computer Vision course.  What I have told you is based on his slides:  http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs4243/lecture/camera.pdf.  Take a look at slides 30-32 if you want to know where I pulled this material from.  However, the MATLAB code I wrote myself :)

Comment: When line `h = A \ b;` run, I get error : "Error using  \ 
Linear algebra is not supported for integer data types.
To compute elementwise LDIVIDE, use LDIVIDE (.\) instead.

Error in rotation (line 46)
h = A \ b; "

Comment: Cast your data to `double` before you start processing. I didn't know your points were of integer type. I've changed my code. Check the edits.

Comment: BTW, I've also assumed that your points are stored as `M x 2` matrices.  The first columns are your `x` values, and your second columns are your `y` values.  Edited my post again to reflect this.

Comment: thank you very much for your collobration. Where I am stuck is converting and implementing mathematical notations of those matrix structures into MATLAB code. I have two grayscale images in seperate matrixes named as Original and Transformed. Assume that I have a formula `F = m * a;`  I know `F`, I know `a`. I have to find out `m`. All the sources tell me to find `F` but I need to find `m`. I hope I could tell my problem with my poor English.

Comment: The code I wrote basically solves for `m`.  I'm not sure where else you are confused.  If you take the MATLAB code I wrote exactly, and condition it to the `M x 2` matrices that I talked about, you should be able to recover the transformation matrix through least squares

Comment: That's great! But I want to ask one more thing: When I get H matrix I get `H = [ -0.6433; -0.0509; 117.4432; -0.6699; 0.0484; 106.9079; -0.0059; 0.0003]`. Why `H(9)` is 0 and not 1?

Comment: Hi there.  You're only solving for the 8 parameters.  We assumed that `H(9)` was 1 so that wasn't modeled in the matrix.  What you're reading is actually `H(8) = 0.0003`!  You can also see that `H(7) = -0.0059`.  Theoretically these should both be zero, but that is the drawback of least squares.  It doesn't completely eliminate the error!  You can also see that your `x` and `y` offsets are `117.4432` and `106.9079` respectively.  Also, use either `H(1), H(2), H(4), H(5)` and apply its respective inverse trig function to get your angle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52627/discussion-between-zkanoca-and-rayryeng)

Comment: What you got there is the solution for a Matrix with all 9 coefficients ! It is a great solution for homografic transform as you showed in your reference. The problem here is more easy because h31=0 and h32=0 !! If you look what you have there you can simplify the mathematical problem